# Fastest way to delete a tree of directories in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io

I need to write a batch file that received a directory that contains a huge number of empty sub-directories and deletes them all.

What's the fastest way of doing this? (by fast I mean not like what Windows Explorer does when you try to delete such a directory...)

**Clarification:**

I'm not trying to delete *only* empty directories. It just so happens that this dir I'm trying to delete is mostly empty sub-dirs.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
rd yourdirname /s/q
```

Will do the job regardless of whether they are empty or not.

Comment: I think the whole point of deleting _empty_ directories is about to _not_ delete the non-empty ones :)

Comment: @Johannes, no that wasn't the point actually. I'll edit and clarify

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I understood the question.  If you just want to delete the tree then you can just use `rd /s`.  However, if you only want to delete *empty* directories, then you can do the following using Cygwin.

```
find -type d -empty | xargs rmdir
```

The standard IT build where I work has Cygwin installed, and I've used this more than once.

Comment: If you have Cygwin installed yoy can do "rm -rf dirname"

Comment: That will erase *all* directories, not only empty ones.